# Why sqlite complains to this code?

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax, syntax-error

I am writing a project and using generation sql for testing, but SQLite explains to my code.

```
INSERT INTO Categories
(CategoryId, Name, UrlName, CategoryIndex)
VALUES
('b2cc232c-0d5c-4f35-bb6f-29c67d7d40c2', 'Using Forums', 'usingforums', 0), 
('ad9b355d-77bf-4a30-b3fe-7d562df2899f', '.NET Development', 'netdevelopment', 1), 
('c4882e5e-4eb5-4e5e-b73a-3bf358bda60e', 'Visual Studio', 'visualstudio', 2), 
('8c611ec3-5c2c-45c2-be01-6595b43155ee', 'Visual C#', 'visualcsharp', 3), 
('c96cea21-de98-4d68-b22b-90eea66d6b77', 'Visual C++', 'visualcpp', 4), 
('c6fb52d5-d4c6-48c2-8892-75f9cb330106', 'Architecture', 'architecture', 5), 
('20616eb8-2273-449b-8f65-a49621b92ea4', 'SQL Server', 'sqlserver', 6)
```

Error:
SQL Execution Error.
Executed SQL statement: INSERT INTO Categories...
Error Source: System.Data.SQLite
Error Message: SQLite error
near "," syntax error

Schema of this table:
    table Categories (
        CategoryId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
       Name TEXT not null,
       UrlName TEXT not null,
       CategoryIndex INTEGER not null,
       primary key (CategoryId)
    )

Why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't just complain. I'm pretty sure it gives you an exact error message. Please post that error message. Also, please post the schema of your Categories table.

Comment: Sorry if this is redundant.  Does SQLite support multiple inserts from one VALUES like SQL Server?  Usually you can only insert one record at a time, unless you use INSERT INTO..SELECT..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite [doesn't allow](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) you to insert multiple rows with the `values` clause.

Try a `union all select` instead:

```
INSERT INTO      Categories
                 (CategoryId, Name, UrlName, CategoryIndex)
          select 'b2cc232c-0d5c-4f35-bb6f-29c67d7d40c2', 'Using Forums', 'usingforums', 0
union all select 'ad9b355d-77bf-4a30-b3fe-7d562df2899f', '.NET Development', 'netdevelopment', 1
....
```

Comment: The linked website seems to indicate that multiple insertions are indeed allowed. Is this a recent addition?

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) doesn't support the multi-values insert syntax - that's a MySQL extension to SQL syntax. You'll have to rewrite this as one-query-per-value-set, so 7 different queries.

Answer (score 0):

Because your SQL is not valid.  You can only insert a single tuple of values in each INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone here has answered thew question - 'why does sql lite complain...' because if you look at the sqlite documentation, it DOES allow multiple values on insert: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html, excerpt:
"The first form (with the "VALUES" keyword) creates one or more new rows in an existing table."

So what is wrong with this code?

```
INSERT INTO "roles" ("description", "name", "rid") VALUES ('Administrator','admin',2), ('Member','member',3)
```

gies this error: Query Error: near ",": syntax error Unable to execute statement

but this works:

```
INSERT INTO "roles" ("description", "name", "rid") VALUES ('Administrator','admin',2)
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference SQLite has somewhat recently added a feature which allows for multiple entries per query delimited by commas as in your example. See user2241515s answer for further info and link.

That said, I have tested this. With new versions of SQLite3 it does work ( 3.7.11+ ) from the console, at least in my case. The problem is it will probably take a while for various SQL parsers to catch up. As an example, I am using Qt for this. The same statement that works in console does not work when executed by a Qt application. The error is the same as above:

> Database error: near ",": syntax error Unable to execute statement

Another possible issue is that SQLite does not allow for large queries (I think the limit is around 500 created rows per query right now). But the error for that looks different.